# Plans on ban cryptocurrencies because of energy crisis

Tags: western-world, energy-policy, cryptocurrency

The Swiss government has issued a set of recommendations to deal with the current energy crisis, including a ban on heated swimming pools and saunas (which completely undermines the concept of a sauna).

Is any Western/European country currently discussing a ban on cryptocurrencies, which are the perfect example of energy waste? It would be strange if people were urged to do extreme savings, but the industry that provides such huge energy usage, while providing no value added for the society, was not. However, I haven't heard of any planned measures yet.

Comment: Cryptocurrency mining is carried out in Europe at rates lower than the global average, and the total energy usage of Bitcoin (the biggest contributor) across the world is about 0.6% of global electric power production. Bitcoin (and some other cryptocurrencies) are wasteful overall, but I do not think that any country in Europe could materially reduce its electricity consumption by banning cryptocurrency. Kazakhstan or even the United States, perhaps.

Comment: @Obie2.0 what percentage is swimming pool heating?

Comment: @user253751 - I never said that swimming pool heating would help much, either.

Comment: @Obie2.0 : 0.6% seems little on first glance, but considering it is of the total **global** consumption, it's still **a lot**. And that's only Bitcoin, and even though it's the biggest, all the others do add up.

Comment: @vsz  - That's worldwide. Europe has disproportionately low Bitcoin energy consumption as a percentage of the total, to my understanding, whereas countries like Kazakhstan and the USA have higher.

Comment: @Obie2.0 : that's true, but when a country or small group of countries propose policies to act on a global scale, they expect, or at least hope, that one day other countries become part of that treaty as well. It has to start *somewhere*, after all.

Comment: @Obie2.0: And even what little energy consumption there is in Europe, a lot of it is concentrated in places where energy and cooling is essentially "free", such as places with lots of waterfalls providing both hydroelectric energy and cooling water. Remember, crypto mining turns electric energy into money, and operates on tight margins. If fossils-fuel produced energy costs rise, the problem will take care of itself.

Answer (score 10):

The New York Senate [passed](https://time.com/6183929/new-york-crypto-mining-moratorium/) the U.S.’s first statewide moratorium on cryptocurrency mining, aimed at energy-intensive operations that use fossil fuels for power. Some miners even repurpose the whole power plants for mining. These may be coal - fired power plants unfortunately.